# remove "duplicate" files shell script

Tags: shell-script, files

I have a list of files named:

> ```
> file.txt
> file (1).txt
> file (2).txt
> file (7).txt
> ```
>
> etc.

Where the greater (number) is the last file updated, but some intermediate numbers might be missing and there are other files on the directory as well.

How to check if there is a "duplicate" file, and if there is, how to copy the content of `file (maxnumer).txt` to `file.txt`, and remove all `file (*).txt` files.

I tried listing them with `ls -t file*(*)*.txt` and then make a `for` loop but it gives me an error (`ls`): `bash:syntax error near unexpected token '('`

Comment: What was the error? What was your loop?

Comment: `ls` gives me the error, i haven't yet got to the for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the timestamps are not reliable, we'd like to find the file that has the largest number in the parenthesis towards the end of the filename.

Doing that:

```
#!/bin/sh

prefix=$1

if [ -z "$prefix" ]; then
    printf 'Usage: %s prefix [ suffix ]\n' "$0" >&2
    exit 1
fi

suffix=$2

for filename in "$prefix ("*")$suffix"; do
    [ ! -f "$filename" ] && continue

    num=${filename##*\(}    # "file (xx).txt" --> "xx).txt"
    num=${num%\)*}          # "xx).txt" --> "xx"

    # if no max number yet, or if current number is higher, update max
    if [ -z "$max" ] || [ "$num" -gt "$max" ]; then
        max=$num
    fi
done

# if we have a max number, use it to rename the file and then remove the other files
if [ -n "$max" ]; then
    printf 'Would move %s to %s\n' "$prefix ($max)$suffix" "$prefix$suffix"
    # mv "$prefix ($max)$suffix" "$prefix$suffix"
    printf 'Would remove %s\n' "$prefix ("*")$suffix"
    # rm "$prefix ("*")$suffix"
else
    printf 'Found no files matching "%s (*)%s"\n' "$prefix" "$suffix"
fi
```

Running it:

```
$ tree
.
|-- file (1).txt
|-- file (2).txt
|-- file (7).txt
|-- file.list
|-- file.txt
`-- script.sh

0 directory, 6 files

$ sh script.sh file .txt
Would move file (7).txt to file.txt
Would remove file (1).txt
Would remove file (2).txt
Would remove file (7).txt
```

(remove the commented out `mv` and `rm` to actually modify files)

This would fail for filenames such as `file (2) (30).txt` (these would also be matched) as it assumes that all filenames follow the pattern `prefix (NN)suffix` where `NN` is an integer.

Comment: last `if` get executed even if there are no `(*)` files...

Comment: maybe it is because i'm triyng to set the files as an input `file=$1`. Does that chages the rest of the script? I'm trying with `if [[ $max == ?(-)+([0-9]) ]]`

Comment: @kurokirasama See update answer. I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve with that test in your previous comment.